# How to randomize this 2D pixel spread function to mimic fire spread?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, 2d

So I have a function that's supposed to mimic the growth and spread of fire on a 2D array representing locations. 
This is how it works:

- Start the fire at a particular location, example (x,y)=(1,1)
- An unvisited pixel has a value of 0.
- 1 - 9 are reserved numbers for objects (like walls, etc).
- A pixel on fire has intensity values from 10 to 40.
- 10 to 20 goes from light red to dark red to show increasing
  intensity.
- 20 to 30 remains dark red to show stagnating intensity. 30 to 40 goes
  from red to dark to    show dying fire.
- The function `findingNeighbors` finds the neighbor pixels of a
  pixel withintensity and increases their intensity.

So far the function works but it is very linear and doesn't work like I thought it would. I thought it would spread in a more radial way. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I would like it to look like real fire spread. I would like a more radial randomized growth pattern.

So my question is what can i do to the function to randomize a bit to show fire spreading from a point without taking a performance hit? Should the function to find neighbors be randomized a bit?

**Runnable code included below**

```
function simulateFire() {
  for (let y = 0; y < mainGrid.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < mainGrid[y].length; x++) {
      let intensity = mainGrid[y][x];
      if (intensity >= 10 && intensity < 40) {
        findingNeighbors(y, x);
        $(`#cell_${y}_${x}`).empty().addClass(`i-${intensity}`).html(intensity);
      }

    }
  }
}

function findingNeighbors(i, j) {
  let rowLimit = mainGrid.length - 1;
  let columnLimit = mainGrid[0].length - 1;

  for (let x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1, rowLimit); x++) {
    for (let y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1, columnLimit); y++) {
      if (x !== i || y !== j) {
        increaseIntensity(y, x);
      }
    }
  }
}

function increaseIntensity (y,x) {  
    if (mainGrid[y][x] === 0 ) {
        mainGrid[y][x] = 10;
    } else if (mainGrid[y][x] > 9 && mainGrid[y][x] < 40) {
        mainGrid[y][x]++;
    }
}
```

```js
let mainGrid = Array(200).fill().map(() => Array(200).fill(0)); // 200 x 200

$(document).ready(() => {
  let fireInterval;
  startFire(1, 1); // start fire at location (1,1)

  addTable(mainGrid, 'table');
  $('#start-btn').on('click', () => {
    fireInterval = setInterval(() => {
      simulateFire();
    }, 500);
  });
  $('#stop-btn').on('click', () => {
    clearInterval(fireInterval);
  })
});


function increaseIntensity(y, x) {
  if (mainGrid[y][x] === 0) {
    mainGrid[y][x] = 10;
  } else if (mainGrid[y][x] > 9 && mainGrid[y][x] < 40) {
    mainGrid[y][x]++;
  }
}


function addTable(dataArray, id) {
  $(`#${id}`)
    .empty()
    .append(`<table id="scene-arr-table" style="border-collapse:collapse;"></table>`);
  dataArray.forEach((el, r) => {
    let row = $(`<tr></tr>`);
    $(`#scene-arr-table`).append(row);
    el.forEach((el, c) => {
      $(row).append(`<td id="cell_${r}_${c}">${el}</td>`)
    });

  });
}

function startFire(y, x) {
  mainGrid[y][x] = 10; // intensity starts at 10
}

function simulateFire() {
  for (let y = 0; y < mainGrid.length; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < mainGrid[y].length; x++) {
      let intensity = mainGrid[y][x];
      if (intensity >= 10 && intensity < 40) {
        findingNeighbors(y, x);
        $(`#cell_${y}_${x}`).empty().addClass(`i-${intensity}`).html(intensity);
      }

    }
  }
}

function findingNeighbors(i, j) {
  let rowLimit = mainGrid.length - 1;
  let columnLimit = mainGrid[0].length - 1;

  for (let x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1, rowLimit); x++) {
    for (let y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1, columnLimit); y++) {
      if (x !== i || y !== j) {
        increaseIntensity(y, x);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.i-0 {
  background: transparent;
}

.i-10 {
  background: red;
}

.i-11 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.i-12 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.i-13 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.i-14 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.i-15 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.i-16 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.i-17 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.i-18 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.i-19 {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.i-20 {
  background: red;
}

.i-21 {
  background: red;
}

.i-22 {
  background: red;
}

.i-23 {
  background: red;
}

.i-24 {
  background: red;
}

.i-25 {
  background: red;
}

.i-26 {
  background: red;
}

.i-27 {
  background: red;
}

.i-28 {
  background: red;
}

.i-29 {
  background: red;
}

.i-30 {
  background: red;
}

.i-31 {
  background: #e60404;
}

.i-32 {
  background: #cd0808;
}

.i-33 {
  background: #b40c0c;
}

.i-34 {
  background: #9b1010;
}

.i-35 {
  background: #821414;
}

.i-36 {
  background: #691818;
}

.i-37 {
  background: #501c1c;
}

.i-38 {
  background: #372020;
}

.i-39 {
  background: #1e2424;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="start-btn" type="button">START SIM</button>
  <button id="stop-btn" type="button">STOP SIM</button>
  <div id="table" style="font-size:2px;">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need two copies of mainGrid, one for the current frame (that you read from) and one for the next frame (that you write into). Otherwise you will propagate the fire all the way through in one pass as you write ahead of where you read. At the end of each frame copy from next into current.

Comment: @samgak could you explain this a bit more? I'm not sure I entirely get the writing ahead of the reading part

Comment: Basically, you want to compute the next state based on the current one. but if you are writing back to mainGrid as you go, you end up modifying the current state before you have finished computing the next state. You overwrite values that you haven't finished using, before you get a chance to use them. e.g. the calculation for 2,0 should be based on the original value of 1,0, not the new value

Comment: I'm assuming that you want the fire to spread by 1 grid cell (in all directions) per call to simulateFire. For cell 0,0 you will call increaseIntensity for the surrounding cells including 1,0 which will increase the value of mainGrid[1][0]. Then you increment x and call increaseIntensity for the cells surrounding 1,0 which will include the original 2,0 and so on. So the fire will go from 0,0 to 2,0 (and further) in one pass. You can see this happening when you run your program, it propagates all the way from the top left to the bottom right in one frame.

Comment: @samgak Oh I see! I get it now! So silly of me! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get it more irregular would be to add some randomness to it. Replace `increaseIntensity(x,y)` with a random parameter, maybe with a non-linear filter and inverse distance.

```
increaseIntensity(x, y, sqrt(rand(0.,1.)) / ((x-i) * (x-i) + (y-j) * (y-j))
```

Another way would be to have a kernel filter. What you have right now is similar to a 3x3 filter with all values 1. I would try a 5x5 filter with some decreased values for the outer pixels. This should give it a more radial look. You'll need to increase the filter size to improve the quality of the fire front. This way you can also construct the filter with higher values in a certain direction to create the illusion of wind influence.

In both cases make sure you don't reuse the new values in the same frame, otherwise your fire will run-away in some direction.

For performance, checkout GPU compute support. These types of operations (kernels) are well supported and very fast.